# jquery get maps.google.com only when document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Inside `<head></head>` placed `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>`

Sometimes it takes too long time to open page. When page loads see `Read maps.gstatic.com`. When removed `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>` page loads fast.

So decided to start to load `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>` only when other part of document loaded.

Tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true");
});
```

But get error `uncaught exception: Google Maps API is required. Please register the following JavaScript library http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true.`

Tried also this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async outside document ready

```
function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = loadScript;
```

Got the same error

What to change to get to load google maps script only after other content loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've ommitted the required callback-parameter in the script-url.

This  callback-parameter is expected to be the name of a global function.

You may not access `google.maps`-properties/methods somewhere before this function has been called, so this function is the place where you should e.g. create a map or request services. Wrap all your `google.maps`-related scripting into this function.

When you load libraries which require the maps-API(e.g. MarkerClusterer) you must also load these libraries asynchronously(in the callback) and run the scripting based on this library when the library has been loaded.

Based on the error-message I guess you want to use the [GMaps](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/)-library(which of course requires the maps-API).

**Sample for asynchronous loading of maps-API and GMaps:**

```js
//script-loader
function loadScript(url,callback){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    if(typeof callback==='function'){
      script.addEventListener('load',callback,false);
    }
    script.setAttribute('src',url);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
  
//callback-function for load of maps-API
function init(){
    alert(['init',
           '---------',
           'google.maps->'+typeof google.maps,
           'GMaps->'+typeof window.GMaps 
          ].join('\n'));
    
    //callback-function for load of GMaps-library
    init2=function(){
       alert(['init2',
           '---------',
           'google.maps->'+typeof google.maps,
           'GMaps->'+typeof window.GMaps 
          ].join('\n'));
      new GMaps({
        div: '#map',
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
        zoom:1
      });
    }
    //load GMaps
    loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gmaps.js/0.4.12/gmaps.min.js',init2);
}

//load the maps-API asynchronously  
window.addEventListener(
 'load',
 function(){
  loadScript('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=init')
 },
 false);
```

```css
      html ,
      body ,
      #map{ 
        height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Struggled a bit with this...ironically, found an even simpler way to get the job done and the document is ready.  They key is to load it synchronously.

```
 <div id="map"></div>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key='Your KEY'>&callback=InitMap&language=en">
 </script>
```